# Can connected Wallet pay for createMint solana-spl?

Tags: solana-wallets-vue, solanaspl-token, vue

I'm using `vue.js`, `solana-wallets-vue` and `@solana/spl-token` to create a mint for the connected user.
I want to `createMint` and set the connected wallet as **payer**.

```
  import * as web3 from '@solana/web3.js'
  import * as token from '@solana/spl-token'
  import { useWallet } from 'solana-wallets-vue'

  const connection = new web3.Connection(
    web3.clusterApiUrl('devnet'),
    'confirmed',
  )
  
  const { publicKey } = useWallet() // public key of the logged user  

  const tokenMint = await token.createMint(
    connection,
    payer, 
    publicKey, // mintAuthority,
    null, // freezAuhtority,
    2
 )
```

Do I need to generate a keypair for this transaction? Or Can I set the payer as the user logged in?

Answer (score 1):

If you're connecting to a wallet, then you won't have access to the `Signer`, since that's protected by the wallet. I don't know what interface `solana-wallets-vue` exposes, but typically it looks like:

```
      const connection = new web3.Connection(
        web3.clusterApiUrl('devnet'),
        'confirmed',
      )
  
      const { publicKey } = useWallet() // public key of the logged user  
      
      // generate a new keypair for the mint
      const mint = web3.Keypair.generate();
      // get the required lamports for rent-exemption on the mint
      const lamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(token.MINT_SIZE);
      // create the transaction
      const transaction = new Transaction().add(
        // first instruction allocates the mint account and assigns it to the token program
        web3.SystemProgram.createAccount({
            fromPubkey: publicKey,
            newAccountPubkey: mint.publicKey,
            space: token.MINT_SIZE,
            lamports,
            programId: token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        }),
        // initialize the account as a mint
        token.createInitializeMintInstruction(mint, 2, publicKey)
    );
    // account creation requires a signature from the account being created
    transaction.partialSign(mint);
    // call whatever sign-and-send-transaction API on the wallet
```

Answer (score 0):

just do this :

```
const tokenMint = await token.createMint(
connection,
publicKey, 
publicKey, // mintAuthority,
null, // freezAuhtority,
2)
```

please note that if the connected wallet is the payer he needs to sign for the transaction

Comment: The second argument of token.createMint() is a Keypair not a publicKey. So I can't do this.

Comment: i'm pretty sure it's a publickKey, i've never seen a keypair as an argument, except for signing, try it ;)